# Cannot get TGT from AD

Tags: java, security, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to get a TGT for authentication from the Active Directory using JAVA.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    URL localURL = super.getClass().getResource("jaas_ntlm_configuration.txt");
    System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", localURL.toString());

    LoginContext localLoginContext = new LoginContext("GetLoginNameKerberos", new SampleCallbackHandler());

    localLoginContext.login();

    Subject localSubject = localLoginContext.getSubject();

    .....
}
catch (LoginException localLoginException) {
    localLoginException.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code works on one server, however, on other server it fails on "localLoginContext.login();" with this output:

```
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\x\krb5cc_x
LSA: Found Ticket
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found PrincipalName
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found EncryptionKey
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found TicketFlags
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found KerberosTime
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found String
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue constructor
LSA: Found Ticket constructor
LSA: Found PrincipalName constructor
LSA: Found EncryptionKey constructor
LSA: Found TicketFlags constructor
LSA: Found KerberosTime constructor
LSA: Finished OnLoad processing
>> Acquire default native Credentials
LSA: Found KrbCreds constructor
LSA: Got handle to Kerberos package
LSA: Response size is 1556
LSA: Principal domain is SUB.DOMAIN.COM
LSA: Name type is 1
LSA: Name count is 1
LSA: Principal domain is SUB.DOMAIN.COM
LSA: Name type is 2
LSA: Name count is 2
LSA: Session key all zero. Stop.
>>> Found no TGT's in LSA
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
    at my.test.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:123)
```

Can you please help me understanding what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be something wrong with your callback handler. It failed when it was about to prompt for username.

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't expect to have to enter username (you expect Single Sign On), then your problem is a known issue: the LSA API won't hand over the TGT's Session Key because that's considered a security loophole. The error message clearly indicates that this is exactly what happened.

There is a Windows Registry key, `AllowTGTSessionKey`, which you can set to true in order to disable this restriction, but this setting is per-workstation and not per-server, so it is not cleary whether this is why it works on one place and not on the other. Another reason may be the Windows version used because this was introduced with XP Service Pack 2, if I remember correctly.

The proper way to achieve Single Sign On in Java is to delegate the handling of TGT to Windows SSPI, a higher-level API similar to the GSS-API. There is a good library that does this for you, which I can personally recommend: WAFFLE.